# AVPlayerViewController landscape orientation after subclassing

Tags: ios, iphone

I have subclassed AVPlayerViewController so that I can show it in landscape mode on iPhone by overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. This works fine. But when I click on cloud at the bottom right to select Subtitle and CC option, it opens in Portrait mode. What could be the reason?

Is there any other way to display AVPlayerViewController in landscape mode without subclassing it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean only creating a simple Class? Because is simple, just create a new Class and add a AVLayer instead of creating an AVPlayerViewController:

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

AVPlayerItem * playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player play];
```

Then override the right methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```